# unique / distinct items in xml using preceding in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to return a list of unique Items. In this case it should return
Item1
Item2

I have tried things as:

```
//Item/Group/Name[not(text()=preceding::Item/Group/Name)]/text()
//Item/Group/Name[not(text()=preceding::Item/Group/Name/text())]/text()
//Item/Group[not(Name/text()=preceding::Item/Group/Name/text())]/Name/text()
```

Just cannot get it to work.

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Group>
            <Name>Item 1</Name>
        </Group>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Group>
            <Name>Item 1</Name>
        </Group>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Group>
            <Name>Item 2</Name>
        </Group>
    </Item>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the work:

```
//List/Item/Group/Name[not(preceding::*/Name/text() = text())]/text()
```

It will return all 'items' names' not preceded by it's repetition.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure if I correctly understood your problem, because now I've realised that your solution also seems to work...

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be the online xpath testing tool that I used that was not working. Gah! Thank you!